# Django/forms Есть форма choice field не получается подключится по foreign key

Tags: python, django

Прошу помочь, где строка ChoiceField не получется выбрать foreign key, если не пишу эту строку все работает, но я хотел задать ему класс, если не задаю choice класс добовляется но значение исчезают, понемаю что нужно использовать choice но какой параметр задавать

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from main.models import SubCategory, Category


class SubCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ChoiceField(label='Категория',required=True, choices=Category.title, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    title = forms.CharField(label='Подкатегория',required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    price = forms.IntegerField(label='Цена',required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    unit = forms.IntegerField(label='Еденица измерения',required=True,widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
        ordering = ('title',)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category        = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price           = models.IntegerField()
    stock           = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit            = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Подкатегория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Подкатегории'
        ordering = ('price',)
```

Comment: Вы же от `ModelForm` наследуетесь.  Зачем вручную все поля прописываете?

Comment: @Александр Да, но я хотел классы добавить изменить css

Comment: для этого достаточно widget-ы переопределить

Comment: @Александр Да все верно, но вот есть у меня модель где есть foreignkey, как мне в виджете передать choice тот foreign key?